# How to insert new row using PHP in SQLITE in table /var/drk.db and to get generated id

Tags: php, sqlite

How to insert new row using PHP in SQLITE in table /var/drk.db and to get generated id ( id is autoincrement primary key in drk table ) ? I looked at http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php but there is no closing connection. Can someone show me, I don't have experience with SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`SQLite3::lastInsertRowID()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lastinsertrowid.php).

Also, [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) might be a better choice for you.